# Is a local Lorentz frame a coordinate chart on a spacetime manifold?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

I am just starting to learn GR. I'm alternating between studying physics books and studying math books. I keep seeing the term  Lorentz frame and I'm not sure what it means mathematically.

Is a local Lorentz frame in mathematical terms a coordinate chart on a manifold?

Comment: Is physics invariant to a displacement in your coordinate chart?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I) Given a point $p\in M$ in a [Lorentzian manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold#Lorentzian_manifold) $(M,g)$ a *local Lorentz frame* at $p$ usually refers to the [tangent space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space) $T_pM$ at $p$, not the manifold $M$ itself.

Note that the tangent space $T_pM$ at $p$ is naturally equipped with a constant metric $g_p: T_pM \times T_pM \to \mathbb{R}$, while the metric $g$ on the manifold $M$ in general could be curved.

II) However, in a neighborhood $\Omega \subseteq T_pM$ around the origin $0\in T_pM$ in the tangent space $T_pM$, there is an [exponential map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_%28Riemannian_geometry%29) $\exp_p: \Omega \to M$ to the manifold $M$.

So in that sense, we can use the exponential map to view $\Omega$ as a [coordinate chart](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CoordinateChart.html) for a neighborhood $U:=\exp_p(\Omega)\subseteq M$ on the manifold $M$.

The relevant curved metric $\exp_p^{\ast}(g|_U)$ in the coordinate chart $\Omega\subseteq T_pM$ is the [pullback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_%28differential_geometry%29) of the metric $g|_U$ in $U\subseteq M$.

Comment: I don't know what an exponential map is but I can tell if I did this would answer my question. Thanks!

Comment: @StanShunpike: the exponential map just tells us that the tangent plane locally approximates the manifold.

Answer (score 2):

In differential geometry, a *frame* for a manifold $M$ is a section of the frame bundle $FM$, the fiber bundle over $M$ whose fiber at $p$ is the set of all bases for $T_p M$, which is the same as $GL(\dim M)$. For any point $p$ in the domain of a coordinate chart $x^\mu$, since the set $\{\frac\partial{\partial x^\mu}\big|_p\}$ is a base, any *coordinate chart* gives you a *frame*.

When $M$ is equipped with a metric, we can consider only orthonormal bases. More generally, let the fiber over $p$ be the set of ordered tuples $v^i$ of tangent vectors at $p$, such that $$g(v^i, v^j) = a^{ij}$$
for some constant symmetric matrix $a^{ij}$ (with the same signature as the metric). This is the same as $O(g)$ -- the orthogonal group for a metric of signature $g$. In general relativity where $g$ has signature $(1,3)$, this is more commonly known as the Lorentz group, and so these are called *Lorentz frames* (or *tetrads*, or *vierbein*).

Note that we need take $a^{ij} = \operatorname{diag}(1,-1,-1,-1)$. In many applications it is convenient to take a *null tetrad* with $a^{01} = -1, a^{23} = 1$.
Note also that a coordinate frame is a Lorentz frame if and only if the domain of the coordinate chart is flat. (Can you see why?)